# Vuetify tabs won't change when changing v-model

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am currently trying to make the active tab change when I put a value in a variable which controls the component, but it doesn't work. I am binding a variable to v-model and then changing that variable with the value I want. The point is, wheter the value is a number or a string, it doesn't matter because the tabs won't work.

```
<v-card flat>
        <v-tabs v-model="tab" fixed-tabs>
            <v-tab v-for="(instance, idx) in tabData" :key="`${idx}`" @click="callChildrenToUpdate(idx)">
            <v-badge color="red" size="18" class="p-2" v-if="instance"></v-badge>
            ...
            </v-tab>
        </v-tabs>
       ...
</v-card>
```

The data:

```
data () {
        return {
            tab: null,
            items: [],
            tabData: this.tabsData
        }
    },
```

And then in the mounted hook I try changing it, but it won't work.

```
this.tab = 87
```

Comment: Change tabs via the UI, and see if ```tab``` value changes using Vue Dev Tools

Comment: Yeah it changes but the tab value when it happens is like: 0, 1, 2... can't it be the key I gave them? It is so weird.

Comment: This works for me using the sandbox provided by Vuetify: https://codepen.io/mrichar1/pen/VwMMeqz

Comment: @mrssolaris no  ```tab``` will go from first to last following 0, 1, 2... respectively.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't work still. In the mounted hook at least. If I do that in the created component, it works.

Answer (score 1):

On this situation, do NOT use template strings when setting the tab key.

So to make it work, change this:

```
<v-tab v-for="(instance, idx) in tabData" :key="`${idx}`" @click="callChildrenToUpdate(idx)">
```

To:

```
<v-tab v-for="(instance, idx) in tabData" :key="idx" @click="callChildrenToUpdate(idx)">
```

Now when you do:

```
this.tab = 87
```

You should get your tabs to go to index `87` (which seems a lot).
If this is actually an ID, you could do a logic like:

```
this.tab = this.tabData.findIndex(i => i.id === 87)
```